# Losing rows when renaming columns in pyspark (Azure databricks)

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a line of pyspark that I am running in databricks:

> df = df.toDF(*[format_column(c) for c in df.columns])

where format_column is a python function that upper cases, strips and removes the characters full stop . and backtick ` from the column names.

Before and after this line of code, the dataframe randomly loses a bunch of rows. If I do a count before and after the line, then the number of rows drops.
I did some more digging with this and found the same behaviour if I tried the following:

> import pyspark.sql.functions as F

> df = df.toDF(*[F.col(column_name).alias(column_name) for column_name in df.columns])

although the following is ok without the aliasing:

> import pyspark.sql.functions as F

> df = df.toDF(*[F.col(column_name) for column_name in df.columns])

and it is also ok if I don't rename all columns such as:

> import pyspark.sql.functions as F

> df = df.toDF(*[F.col(column_name).alias(column_name) for column_name in df.columns[:-1]])

And finally, there were some pipe (|) characters in the column names, which when removed manually beforehand then resulted in no issue.
As far as I know, pipe is not actually a special character in spark sql column names (unlike full stop and backtick).

**Has anyone seen this kind of behaviour before and know of a solution aside from removing the pipe character manually beforehand?**

Running on Databricks Runtime 10.4LTS.

**Edit**

format_column is defined as follows:

```
def format_column(column: str) -> str:
    column = column.strip().upper()  # Case and leading / trailing white spaces
    column = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", column)  # Multiple white spaces
    column = re.sub(r"\.|`", "_", column)

    return column
```

**Edit 30/05/2023**

I am now seeing this problem again and while it is difficult to re-produce still seems mysterious.

Comment: Why use df.toDF() if it is already a dataframe? Are you sure your function format_column only renames columns and not the content within that column? How does this function look like?

Comment: Why not to try `.select` instead of `toDF` ?

Comment: I have added edited the question with a definition of `format_column`. We are using `.toDF` in order to create a new dataframe, this seemed clearer than using select

Comment: @MMarshall, I have reproduced the above with a sample data and there is no lose of the rows in my dataframe.https://i.imgur.com/P8qDDFS.png.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this in my environment and there is no loss of any rows in my dataframe.

**`format_column` function and my dataframe:**

[image]

When I used the `format_column` as same, you can see the count of dataframe before and after replacing.

[image]

Please recheck your dataframe if something other than this function is changing your dataframe.

If you still getting the same, you can try and check if the following results losing any rows or not.

```
print("before replacing : "+str(df.count()))
df1=df.toDF(*[re.sub('[^\w]', '_', c) for c in df.columns])
df1.printSchema()
print("before replacing : "+str(df1.count()))
```

[image]

If this also results losing rows, then the issue is with something else in your dataframe or code. please recheck on that.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation, I am now failing to re-create this myself too.